# what is the most efficient technology for pumping huge amounts of seawater to great heights

Tags: pumps

if we had to pump up huge amounts of water, almost 5 million metric cubes per hour to a height of 800 meters what would be the most energy-efficient solution?
how much energy would this consume? and how much would the infrastructure cost?

Comment: Efficiency? Height? Would be dropping huge amounts of water from height in order to raise other water.  It could involve huge pipes and cost a huge amount, of energy and a huge amount in infrastructure.

Comment: Check out Dinorwig. generate when demand is high and pumps back at night.

Comment: Which question? efficient? cost? source of energy?

Comment: pumps and pipes.  The main energy will be raising the height of the water.  This question is a bit much for this forum.

Comment: @SolarMike we already have that kind of technology, but since they are used for both pumping and power generation the efficiency for pumping alone is not maximized.

Comment: You did not ask for "NEW" technology or did you just fail to be clear in your question?

Comment: @SolarMike  no i don't want a new technology. i just meant i don't need to look at Dinorwig, we have similar projects here as well. and as i said the turbine/pump technology is designed to be optimized both ways, i don't need both ways.

Answer (score 2):

Water is usually pumped to great heights to be used as a battery, if this is the case companies like ANDRITZ have been doing this sort of thing with the aid of a 220MW Francis pump-turbines. [Project in portugal at 700m of head](https://www.andritz.com/hydro-en/hydronews/hn35/gouvaes-portugal)

Comment: so therefore the efficiency would be as stated here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_turbine

Comment: I couldn't find a pumping efficiency on that page. I don't know if sea-water is an issue to for the pumping system either.

Comment: hmm, yes there seems to be a distinction between the pump and turbine efficiency. This type may be more efficient acting as a turbine.

Comment: Similar sized radial flow pumps are available by VOITH, but again no efficiency is stated. But they must be efficient enough if they are on the market if that makes sense. https://voith.com/corp-en/11_06_Broschuere-Pumped-storage_einzeln.pdf

Comment: So five of those beasts get you 11 billion watts. That's in the ball park, depending on the pipe length. Some of the systems in Central America run 25 miles lake to lake.

Comment: i was actually thinking about guiding the seawater to Iranian deserts to increase rainwater and humidity. this would mean carrying water for over a thousand kilometers to the heights of 300-800 meters. Francis turbines are used for both power generation and water pump and are not the most efficient way for pumping alone are they?

Comment: @aSaffary Have a look at the link with the VOITH radial pumps.

Comment: @SamiSafarini yes that was quite helpful too thanks. i have also found this one https://www.andritz.com/resource/blob/80826/c99021308f65b2e65e43babe2181aae7/pumps-portfolio-en-data.pdf